# Proving continuity using gluing lemma

Tags: continuity, metric-spaces

> Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be defined as $f(x) = x$ if $||x||\le1$ and $ \frac{x}{||x||^2}$ if $||x||> 1$. Show that $f$ is continuous.

*My attempt:* $||x||\le 1$ $\iff x \in B[0,1] = U_1$ and $||x||>1$ $\iff$ $x\in X - B[0,1] = U_2$, it's clear that $f(x) \mid_{x\in U_1}$ is continuous since it is an identity map. Since $||\,.||$ is a continuous function from $X \to\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$,  $f(x) \mid_{x\in U_2}$ is also continuous. The problem arises when I want to apply the gluing theorem. In the theorem, either all $U_{i}'s$ are open or closed. In this case $U_1$ is closed and $U_2$ is open. So how do I proceed from here?

---

(Gluing Lemma): Let $X$ and $Y$ be (metric) spaces.

1. Let $\{U_i : i \in I\}$ be a family of open sets such that $\cup_{i} U_i = X$. Assume that there exists a continuous function $f_i: U_i \to Y$ for each $i \in  I$ with the property that $f_i(x) = f_j(x)$ for all $x \in U_i \cap U_j$ and $i,j \in I$. Then the function $f: X \to Y$ defined by setting $f(x) := f_i(x)$ if $x \in U_i$ is well-defined and continuous on $X$.
2. Let $\{A_i : i \in F\}$ be a finite family of closed sets such that $\cup_{i} A_i = X$. Assume that there exists a continuous function $f_i: A_i \to Y$ for each $i \in  F$ with the property that $f_i(x) = f_j(x)$ for all $x \in A_i \cap A_j$ and $i,j \in F$. Then the function $f: X \to Y$ defined by setting $f(x) := f_i(x)$ if $x \in A_i$ is well-defined and continuous on $X$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply 2) to the closed sets $\{x: \|x\| \leq 1\}$ and $\{x: \|x\| \geq 1\}$ and the functions $x$ and $\frac x {\|x\|^{2}}$.

Comment: By changing the conditions, won't it change the function? So we will be proving continuity of a different function and not $f$.

Comment: @Sabhrant No. Your function may appear to be different from  mine at first sight but they are one and the same. If $\|x\|=1$ then your definition gives $f(x)=x$ and mine gives $f(x)=\frac x {\|x\|^{2}}$ but aren't these same (since $\|x\|=1$)?

Comment: Thank you sir 